# How to control file's opening and downloading?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2.
How to control file's opening and downloading?
Like this:

```
xxx.php?filename=0001.jpg
```

Sometimes browser will show the image ,and sometimes will show a file download  box ?How to control it?

Comment: This all depends upon what you  are actually doing. Some code/html would be useful

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Thanks, is there some code examples?

Comment: @Sougata Thanks, is there some code examples?

Answer (score 2):

Please, read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#file-downloads).

Example:

```
public function getFile()
{
    $file = public_path(). "/path/to/file.jpg";
    $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'];

    // For download
    return response()->download($file, 'someName.jpg', $headers);

    // For display
    return response()->file($file, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am used for download file function:

```
public function download($file){
  $path = public_path('PATH/TO/YOUR/'. $file);
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Content-type: ".mime_content_type($path));
  header("Content-length: " . filesize($path));
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
  header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$file.'";');
  readfile($path);
}
```